# Enabling Caching for certain css and js files in MVC3

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, caching, browser

Would like to inquire if there is any method to Enabling caching for certain files/folder in ASP.Net MVC3

The target files are some CSS and Jquery js files which are likely not to change for a long period.

Kind regards,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Configure the HTTP Expires Response Headers from IIS, it is very simple, just check **Expire Web content**

http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc770661(v=ws.10).aspx

And yes, use bundling! It will generate unique hash, scripts and styles will be recached when any file changes in the bundle.